# How to update a many-to-many association with Ecto

Tags: elixir, associations, phoenix-framework

I have a Phoenix app with two resources that have a many to many relationship. To simplify, let's call them posts and tags. When I create a post from scratch, I can associate existing tags with it. I can also edit a post that has no tags to associate tags with it. However, whenever I want to edit which tags are associated with a post, I get this error:

```
you are attempting to change relation :tags of MyApp.Posts.Post but the `:on_replace` option of
this relation is set to `:raise`
```

Here is my changeset - I'm using `put_assoc` which has 4 arguments, but according to the docs, the opts one isn't used so I can't set the on_replace option:

```
def changeset(%__MODULE__{} = user, attrs) do
    tag_ids = if attrs["tags"], do: attrs["tags"], else: []
    tags = Tags.by_ids(tag_ids)

    user
    |> Repo.preload(:tags)
    |> cast(attrs, [:title, :body])
    |> put_assoc(:tags, tags)
    |> validate_required([:body])
  end
```

The idea is to only update the association between the two - I would never create or delete tags themselves from the posts form. Should I be updating them in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that ecto doesn't know what to do with you updating directly an already existing relation between your user and tags, should it delete all and insert only the new ones, should it add to the existing ones?

By default, as the error says, it will `:raise` an error.

The option it mentions is declared on the relation and not when casting/putting assocs, as documented [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#many_to_many/3)

In order to always use the tags that are being put on the changeset, you should add this option on the relationship

```
many_to_many :tags, MyApp.Tag, join_through: "posts_tags", on_replace: :delete
```

More info on this option [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#module-the-on_replace-option)

Comment: Thanks! I think I was confused because the explanation in the docs was in the section about cast_assoc and put_assoc.